# How to show$\sum_{k=0}^n{\left({n\choose{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}\right)} = 2^{2n-2}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I know that $\sum_{k=0}^n{\left({n\choose{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}\right)} = 2^{2n-2}$, but I can't figure out how to prove it. The sum came up in the context of a probability question, which can be solved via symmetry to show that the above is indeed $2^{2n-2}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{j} = \sum_{0\leq j < k \leq n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{j} \tag{1}$$
can be written, by setting $d=k-j$, as
$$ \sum_{d=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-d}\binom{n}{j+d}\binom{n-1}{n-j-1}\stackrel{\text{Vandermonde}}{=}\sum_{d=1}^{n}\binom{2n-1}{n-d}=\sum_{d=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{d}\tag{2}$$
and the last sum is clearly half the sum $\sum_{d=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{d} = 2^{2n-1}$, hence:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{j}=\color{red}{2^{2n-2}}\tag{3}$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that
$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}} 
= 2^{2n-2}
$.

I almost do this,
but there are two unexplained terms
in my answer
that prevent this.

So,
I'll show what I have done
and see is someone else
can find what is wrong.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}\\ 
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n{n\choose{k}} {{n-1}\choose{j}}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}\sum_{k=j+1}^n{n\choose{k}} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}(\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose{k}}-\sum_{k=0}^j{n\choose{k}}) \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}(2^n-\sum_{k=0}^j{n\choose{k}}) \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}2^n-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}\sum_{k=0}^j{n\choose{k}}\\ 
&=2^{n-1}2^n-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^j{{n-1}\choose{j}}{n\choose{k}} \\
&=2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}{n\choose{k}} \\
&=2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k}{{n-1}\choose{j}}\\
&=2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k}{{n-1}\choose{j}} +{n\choose{n}} \sum_{j=0}^{n}{{n-1}\choose{j}}\\
&=2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{k}} ({{n-1}\choose{k}}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}}) +2^{n-1}\\
&=2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{k}} {{n-1}\choose{k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{k}}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{{n-1}\choose{j}} +2^{n-1}\\
&=2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{k}} {{n-1}\choose{k}}-s(n) +2^{n-1}\\
\text{so}\\
2s(n)
&=2^{2n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose{k}} {{n-1}\choose{k}} +2^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

At this point I am puzzled.
If those last two terms
were not there,
we would have
$s(n) = 2^{2n-2}$.

But they are there.

So either I have made a mistake
or the original question is wrong.

I don't know which it is,
so I'll leave it at this.